# 3D Mesh modification by collisions push in runtime in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh

please can i have a little help guidance in something, a about mesh curving , kind of look around but would like your advice
This object (the circle shape) is getting deformed like the yellow part, what do you advice me about it please?
Any script to see the mechanic or similar examples? (Attached gif)
I tried to see some but only works with mouse click ( I am very new to mesh binding )
[Like What you watching here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqQHe.gif)
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would start by describing the whole shape as list of points.
Then you should be able to move those points either via physics or "manually" (by doing Physics2D.OverlapPoint and some math during movement).

With that it's just a matter of constructing runtime mesh, there are tutorials on how to do that (I think Freya Holmér has one), just look for "procedular geometry" or similar.